# Is running stereoCalibrate after calibrateCamera redundant?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a stereo camera rig. I have captured a chessboardPattern sequence (the same sequence, two pictures per exposure). I have performed a single camera calibration on the individual cameras using cv2.calibrateCamera.

My question is, is running a cv2.stereoCalibrate on both cameras redundant, given that calibrateCamera has provided me with object-relative position and orientation of the individual cameras? If not, what benefits does it provide me with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intrinsic parameters are generated in both cv2.stereoCalibrate and cv2.calibrateCamera using the same function 'cvCalibrateCamera2', the difference being in cv2.stereoCalibrate you disable can this calculation using the flags.

'No', this functionality is  not redundant because the extrinsic parameters are calculated in a different manner. What calibrateCamera does for you as demonstrated in [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) tutorial is how to find 3D points using a **single** camera over multiple frames, which is what a stereo camera can do in a single frame (taken by both cameras). In stereoCalibrate, the extrinsic parameters are generated with respect to both the cameras.

Since you already have a stereo rig, use stereoCalibrate to get the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. [This](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html) page has information about how to use those parameters to create a depth map.

[OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Comment: Perhaps my question should have read: is running calibrateCamera before stereoCalibrate redundant? Your answer (thank you) implies that running calibrateCamera to estimate intrinsics is not necessary, since ultimately we perform the same step in stereoCalibrate. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, the intrinsic parameters include information specific to each individual camera such as lens distortion and focal length, while the extrinsic parameters describe relative positional information in the form of translation and rotation matrix. If the intent is to execute OpenCV stereo functions, then there is no point calling calibrateCamera, just use stereoCalibrate.

Comment: StereoCalibrate appears to take camera matrices are parameters, if we don't estimate the individual camera matrices first, then what do we include in the parameters?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 From the documentation "If any of CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS , CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO , CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC , or CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH are specified, some or all of the matrix components must be initialized. See the flags description for details." See [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5). Still uncertain, tough. I will try.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised at how sloppy the documentation is.